# Java Library for conversion from dot to xdot

Tags: java, dot

I am currently developing a webapp in Java for which the main output is a graph in the dot-format. For the visualization part I want to use CanViz which needs xdot as input. So far I couldn't find any Java-Library which converts dot to xdot.
Does anyone know such a Library?

I already tried running "dot graph.cv -Txdot -ograph-xdot.gv" via exec, unfortunately that did not work. (Cannot run program "dot": error=2, No such file or directory)

Thanks in advance,
Moritz

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion:

http://www.loria.fr/~szathmar/off/projects/java/GraphVizAPI/index.php

provides a nice wrapper for calling dot from Java.